# Optional match extends query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I add an optional match to my already working query the selection is expanded.

I have a structure regarding players in games as follows
(player)-[got]->(result)-[in]->(game)

And as players oppose each other things will look like this in the final data 
(player_1)-[got]->(result_1)-[in]->(game)<-[in]-(result_2)-[got]-(player_2)

Given a list of **result_1** ids I try to find corresponding **result_2**

The basic query

```
MATCH (r:Result)-[:In]->(g:Game)<-[:In]-(or:Result)  
WHERE r.id IN [30,32] 
RETURN r, or, g, m
```

returns exactly what I expect:

1. (30)-(g1)-(or1)
2. (32)-(g2)-(or2)

But games can also be in an (optional) match and this query

```
MATCH (r:Result)-[:In]->(g:Game)<-[:In]-(or:Result)     
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)<-[:Contains]-(m:Match) 
WHERE r.id IN [30,32] 
RETURN r, or, g, m
```

returns

1. (30)-(g1)-(or1)
2. (32)-(g2)-(or2)
3. (33)-(g3)-(or3)
4. (n)-(gn)-(orn)
5. Whatever else happens to match the structure p-r-g-r-p but with no regard to the list [30,32]

I do suspect that it has something to do with the mirrored nature of the data because if I remove **r** from the returned values I still get (30) and (32) back as **or** but I cannot figure out why and thus how to stop it.

I've tried to add a With before the optional but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause modifies the immediately preceding `[OPTIONAL] MATCH` or `WITH` clause.

You need to move your `WHERE` clause so it is right after the initial `MATCH`, so that it will limit `r` as you intended. Like this:

```
MATCH (r:Result)-[:In]->(g:Game)<-[:In]-(or:Result)     
WHERE r.id IN [30,32] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)<-[:Contains]-(m:Match) 
RETURN r, or, g, m
```

Comment: When knowing it it seems quite obvious really.